# Disk space taken by Docker Bind Mount and how to delete it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, diskspace

After learning and using Docker with Bind Mount I have realized that a lot of extra space has been taken from my disk...

I have been able to remove all the volumes from the docker desktop (not much difference) but I have no idea where to find those Bind Mounts I have created, where to check the space taken by them and last, how to delete them.

I have run the command

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          0         0         0B        0B
Containers      0         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     500       0         16.09GB   16.09GB
```

What is that Build Cache and how to deal with it?

I have checked also the Docker Engine config file:

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
}
```

Do those 20GB reserved mean that it has been taken from my disk for Docker?

I deleted ALL my containers, images and volumes, so I only have that Cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `docker builder prune -a` command to remove all unused build cache. [HERE](https://github.com/JamesJJ/docker-builder-prune) you can find a nice script that periodically check space usage and run the cleaning.

Comment: One more thing I forgot... What if, in the docker conifg object, I declare, inthe property "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB, less GB to use instead of those 20? Could I change it to 10GB for instance without any problem?

Comment: defaultKeepStorage will use **up to** 10 gb before garbage collector cleanup, so i think it should be safe